# Paste Data instead of Message Box

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Using the help of some tutorials I have managed the below code to download data from a website. However the data is shown as a message box in excel and I'd like to edit this so it pastes the data instead. Is anyone able to assist?

Thanks in advance!

Sub SharePrice()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

website = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN.L/history?p=RTN.L"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "GET", website, False

request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat,1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

html.body.innerHTML = response

price = html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Pstart(10px)")(4).innerText

MsgBox price

End Sub

Comment: Have you tried searching for something like "how to write text to the clipboard in VBA" or similar?

Comment: The 2nd snippet in the top-voted answer in the linked post should help you get going. Cheers!